# выборка уникальных данных с использованием count, max

Tags: sql, запрос, join, count

Суть запроса:Вывод ФИО клиентов и самый предпочитаемый вид услуги у каждого из них за год(выбран 2019 год в запросе).
Самым предпочитаемым считается тот вид услуги который заказывался наибольшее количество раз.
Как показано на картинке я нахожу для каждого клиента сколько раз он заказывал конкретную услугу.
Итак вопрос: как мне вывести для каждого клиента именно одну услугу которую он заказал наибольшее количество раз. Тоесть 1 клиент 1 услуга.
Должно получиться так:
Абрашина    Галина  Ефимовна    Калифорнийское мелирование  1
Андронов    Мир Платонович  Балаяж  1
Антипов Степан  Арсениевич  Стрижка женская с укладкой люкс 2
[image: Диаграмма бд]
[image: запрос и выборка]

Comment: Приветствую на СО.  Дополните условие: что выводить, если количества одинаковые?

Comment: И укажите таки СУБД. Включая версию.